# React: Send array only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm using **React** and **axios** to fetch and post data on a simple list.

On `post` in the console I have the following :

```
{data: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "http://localhost:8000/api/social/reorder/", method: "post", data: "{"order":[{"id":2,"order":1},{"id":1,"order":2},{"id":3,"order":3}]}", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
data: ""
headers: {cache-control: "no-cache, private", connection: "close", content-type: "text/html; charset=UTF-8", date: "Thu, 22 Apr 2021 16:48:09 GMT, Thu, 22 Apr 2021 16:48:09 GMT", host: "localhost:8000", …}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
```

Meaning that the new pushed data is :

```
data: "{"order":[{"id":2,"order":1},{"id":1,"order":2},{"id":3,"order":3}]}"
```

**I guess the problem is that I need only the array without `order` for the database to be able to update the infos**, like this :

```
[{"id":2,"order":1},{"id":1,"order":2},{"id":3,"order":3}]
```

So each field of my table will receive a new order corresponding to their `id`.

For now, the data is **pushed** as you can see in the console but **not registered in the datatabse**. So the data sent is definitely wrong, and I'm suspecting the `order`.

My functions :

```
function handleChangeOrder() {

  const items = Array.from(list);
  let newSequence = [];
  items.forEach((item, index) => {
      newSequence.push({ id: item.id, order: index + 1 });
  });
  axiospost(newSequence);  
  
}


async function axiospost(order){  

try {
  const response = await  axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/social/reorder/', {order});
  return response.data;

} catch (error){console.error("Not able");}

}
```

My backend controller if it can help :

```
public function reorder(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,['order'=>'required']);
        $order = $request->input('order');

        DB::transaction(function () use ($order){
            foreach ($order as $value){
                Social::find($value['id'])->update(['order'=>$value['order']]);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Try removing the curly braces around `order` in the axios call.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan Doesn' work :(. It gives me this `app.js:18334 POST http://localhost:8000/api/social/reorder/ 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: @YaakovAinspan And in laravel.log `[2021-04-22 21:55:50] local.ERROR: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() `

Comment: I just tried this out, and the data being received by the backend is fine with your original code. Why are you using `DB::transaction`? Also, maybe instead of using `foreach`, you could use the `collect` method (I'm pretty sure you're using Laravel, right?)

Comment: @YaakovAinspan Thank you for your answer. Yes I'm using Laravel. I used `DB::transaction` because of a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wk0VZ_oOW30&list=PLkZU2rKh1mT8XhRiPQXiGmK6XwnhYfgQc&index=10&ab_channel=AmitavRoy) . I had no idea about it usage, and I tried without it and it didn't work. Is `collect` the same as `foreach` ?

Comment: Try using something like this: https://pastebin.com/z9mp05We

Comment: @YaakovAinspan It says `app.js:18334 POST http://localhost:8000/api/social/reorder/ 422 (Unprocessable Entity)` . If you have any other method to update the order my a list using React and Laravel I will be more than welcome, as I struggled very bad on this one while following that tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the problem in my controller's syntax, as the data was passing to the DB, but the syntax was faulty.

While updating, I should've used `where` instead of `find` like the following :

```
 DB::transaction(function () use ($order){
            foreach ($order as $value){                
                Social::where('id', $value['id'])->update(['order' =>$value['order']]);
            }
        });
```